# VTEX CMS Storefront customization on Checkout

Tags: css, content-management-system, e-commerce, customization, store

I have a VTEX CMS Storefront store, and I need to customize the checkout process. I've followed a lot of documentation from VTEX, and here's what I've done so far:

- Installed VTEX IO CLI.
- Created a development workspace and installed the 'checkout-ui-custom' locally.
- Used a VTEX link command to apply the necessary CSS styles from the provided URL.
- The only file I needed to work with was 'checkout6-custom.css.'

Now, I've completed the customization, and I'm trying to apply it to a production workspace. However, I'm encountering an issue.

It's not allowing me to use the 'vtex link' command and is asking me to create a development workspace instead.

I'm concerned about whether it's possible to publish the changes I've made in my store as a CMS version. When I checked the 'Layout' > 'File Manager' > '.css,' I couldn't find 'checkout6-custom.css.' I can create a file with this name, but the file on my website has a version hash in its URL, and the changes don't seem to take effect.

If I manually change the version in the .css file URL, I can see the changes. Does anyone know how to help me with this issue?

Thank you!

I tried to customize the checkout proccess on a VTEX CMS Store and publish it on production, but I can't take my changes to a production branch or master branch to publish it to my clients and can't find the file to edit on Layout section of CMS

Answer (score 0):

**About development**

First you need to access your Store Theme folder to install the 'checkout-ui-custom' inside your Store Theme and your file 'checkout6-custom.css' should be in a folder also called 'checkout-ui-custom' inside your Store Theme root.

After that, you'll need to create a development workspace and link your app.

`vtex use featureName` -> to create the development workspace

`vtex link` -> to link your app to your workspace

`vtex browse` -> to open your workspace at the default browser

**About deploy to master**

> Unlike the Development Workspace, the production workspace does not
> allow the `vtex link` command, which is used to link your application
> only to development workspaces.

Then if all works good, the next step is to generate a new release of the Store Theme with your adjustments (in this case, the installation and checkout-ui-custom adjustments)

`vtex release minor stable` - if it's about a new feature, big changes

`vtex release minor patch` - if it's a bug fix, small changes

Create a Productive Workspace.

`vtex use homolog --production`

Install the new release to the Productive Workspace to test your changes in a productive environment.

`vtex install`

If all works good, you can deploy to master.

`vtex deploy`

Finally, promote your production workspace to master if something was change using the site editor

`vtex workspace promote`

**About Documentation**

https://developers.vtex.com/docs/guides/vtex-io-documentation-making-your-new-app-version-publicly-available#optional-promote-your-changes-to-master